# how to display ion-item in ion-row with alternate color in it?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
<ion-row   *ngFor="let box of Boxes"   >
  <ion-col col-9>
  <ion-item  >
  {{box}}
  </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-3>
      <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-col>

</ion-row>
```

How to display item in alternate color ? alternate color for every  row item.?

Comment: Just for confirmation, you want to apply color on ion-row right ?

Comment: yes , i want to display row color alternate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Try this:**

**.html**

```
<ion-row   *ngFor="let box of Boxes; let i = index;">
    <ion-col col-9>
        <ion-item  [ngClass]="(i % 2 == 0) ? 'odd' : 'even'">
            {{box}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3>
        <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

**.scss**

```
.odd{
  color: blue;
}
.even{
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

**.html**

```
<ion-row   *ngFor="let box of Boxes">
    <ion-col col-9>
        <ion-item  class="custom-bg">
            {{box}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3>
        <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

**.scss**

```
.row-custom-bg:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: green;
}
.row-custom-bg:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: blue;
}
```

I think it will be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

You can use even odd properties of ngFor

```
<ion-row   *ngFor="let box of Boxes; let odd=odd; let even=even;
[ngClass]="{ odd: oddStyleClass, even: evenStyleClass }   >
```

Here oddStyleClass and evenStyleClass will define background color or any other style you want to apply

Comment: ` 
  <ion-row   *ngFor="let box of Boxes"  let odd=odd; let even=even;
  [ngClass]="{ odd: oddStyleClass, even: evenStyleClass }"   >
  <ion-col col-9>
  <ion-item  >
  {{box}}
  </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-3>
      <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-col>
  
  </ion-row>` and in background css `  .evenStyleClass{
        background-color:grey;
    }

    .oddStyleClass{
        color:red;
    }` but its not working ?